# tmux unbind arrow keys

Tags: tmux

Having switched to vim-style pane navigation in tmux with the following:

```
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R
```

How can I turn off the original key bindings, specifically `C-a <arrow key>`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `unbind-key`:

```
unbind Left
unbind Down
unbind Up
unbind Right
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to stick to vim-like navigation, would be useful to remap the `resize-pane` also:

```
# vim-like pane resizing  
bind -r C-k resize-pane -U
bind -r C-j resize-pane -D
bind -r C-h resize-pane -L
bind -r C-l resize-pane -R

# vim-like pane switching
bind -r k select-pane -U 
bind -r j select-pane -D 
bind -r h select-pane -L 
bind -r l select-pane -R 

# and now unbind keys
unbind Up     
unbind Down   
unbind Left   
unbind Right  

unbind C-Up   
unbind C-Down 
unbind C-Left 
unbind C-Right
```

I'll show you my `.tmux.conf` as an [example](https://github.com/dminca/dotfiles/blob/master/dotfiles/.tmux.conf#L34-L62)

And by the way, don't forget to remap the `'horizontal-split'` in case you have it on the <kbd>h</kbd> key as it will interfere with your `pane-resize` and `pane-switch`.